Merging 2 netCDF files leading to empty dimensions & variables
I'm trying to merge 2 netCDF files following the recommendation suggested at Combine multiple NetCDF files into timeseries multidimensional array python. The line to combine the file reads:
dataset = nc.MFDataset(['first_file','second_file'])

I noticed that dataset is now defined as an object of the class 'netCDF._netCDF4.MFDataset' instead of Dataset, which seems reasonable. The attributes are fine, but the problem is that dimensions and variables are empty. For example for time, the dimension should be 48 (24+24) but it's not there. Any suggestions on what might be causing this behavior?
